# LINQ query is too slow, Equivalent SQL is fine

Tags: c#, sql, linq, time, analysis

I am trying to query for daily active users in a database using C# and LINQ. I have a SQL query that works fine. It finishes running in < 4 seconds.

My table is called Logins, with properties: (DATETIME)Date, (GUID)UserId, etc

```
SELECT CAST([DATE] AS DATE) Date , COUNT (DISTINCT USERID) DailyActives
  FROM  Logins
  GROUP BY CAST([DATE] AS DATE)
  ORDER BY CAST([DATE] AS DATE)
```

Which counts the distinct users that logged in on that day. My LINQ query that gives the correct answer, but very slowly (Many minutes). Here I am selecting from a specific month

```
from rows in Logins
where rows.Date.Month == 04 && rows.Date.Year == 2013 
group rows by rows.Date.Day into MyGroup
orderby MyGroup.Key
select new
    {
      LoginDate = MyGroup.Key,
      Count = MyGroup.Select(u => u.UserId).Distinct().Count()

    }
```

After testing, it seems like the Count statement takes forever when I have to Select(u=>u.UserId) because I think it has to map back to the list of UserId's. How can i write the query more efficiently?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try PLINQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx

Comment: @Tim.Tang This sounds like a DB Linq query (L2SQL/L2EF) so PLINQ won't help.

Comment: They aren't doing exactly the same because you don't have a WHERE clause in the SQL also you are not getting just that day because you are grouping (slow). I will post the way I would do it you are free to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do as follows...

```
var UserCount = Logins.Where(x => x.Date = DateTime.Today)
                    .Select(x => x.UserId).Distinct().Count();
```

You can of course substitute the day with whichever day you would like to get the count for.

Comment: Thanks! That converts into efficient SQL, and I can simply iterate through to get all the days in a month. Much appreciated!